# understanding support and compatibility in build.gradle for Media style notification

Tags: android, notifications, android-mediaplayer, build.gradle

I am trying to learn to add media controls in order to control play/pause of stream getting played in one of my lerning application fragment. I was able to create layout (with play / pause buttons) in fragment and was able to use MediaPlayer in order to play stream from web.

Now I am learning to add a service and put notification where user still can listen the steam and control the steam with play/pause/stop option.

For this I am referring to the link

http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/using-android-media-style-notifications-with-media-session-controls/165

Application has support with min API level 14. when I am trying example from above link it shows error for MediaController.getTransportControls() function saying "current min SDK support version is 14 and above is is for 21"

For some of functionality to support older API levels,I have seem examples of adding support entries in build.gradle.

If I need to add this functionality for an app with my api level 14, would there be any support entry needs to be added or this cannot be added to an application which has min api level < 21.

if so any alternative I can learn in order to support api level > 14 and still add medial controls to notifications.